# How do write a regex for parse math expressions divided by comma in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have this string **a,[b,c,d], e(f), g(h + i) = j, a + c = g(e)**

How can I write a regex to parse it to array like below?

```
=> Array
     [1] => a
     [2] => [b,c,d]
     [3] => e(f)
     [4] => g(h + i) = j
     [5] => a + c = g(e)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given you have almost 3k rep, you should know better than to post a "gimme teh codez" question...

Comment: This seems like the wrong approach, why can't you change your data? all you need is a space after that first comma.

Comment: The space in my string is not important. So, it can be every where not only after the first comma.

Comment: Are nested strucures like a,[b,[c,d],e] a possibility?

Comment: I my case there no case with nested structures.

Comment: How about empty entries like a,,b,c,d?  Or other edge cases? - Notwithstanding the current answers, for forming suitable expressions one needs to know what assumptions can be made about the input.

Comment: your anwser and user887675's answer solved empty entries flawlessly. For more discussion, I think maybe it also like nested structures and g(a,b,c).

Comment: For entries like g(a,b,c) I used this: /((\[|\()[^])]+(\]|\))|[^,]?[a-z]\([^)]+\)|[^,]+)/g.

Comment: It also works for (a,b,c) entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/(\[[^]]+\]|[^,]+)/g
```

http://regex101.com/r/xV2uA6

use `preg_match_all` to get the matches

http://www.php.net/preg_match_all

Comment: You should use `[^]]+` instead of `.+` or you'll match too much in `[a,b],c,[d]`. Though we know nothing of the possible input...

Comment: Good point, edited the answer.

Comment: I trimmed all space and used below RE for expanded cases like (a,b,c),g(a,b,c),g(a,b)=f(c,d),g(a,b)=f(c,d)+h(e,f),g(a,b)=f(c,d)+h(e,f),g(a,b)-f(c,d)=h(e,f),g(a,b)*f(c,d)+h(e,f)=f(t,y). the RE is /((\[|\()[^])]+(\]|\))|[^,]?\w*\([^)]+(\)=(?R)|\)-(?R)|\)+(?R)|\)\*(?R)|\)\/(?R)|\)|)|[^,]+)/g

Comment: ((\[|\()[^])]+(\]|\))|([^,]?\w*\(|[^,]?[\w.]*=[\w.]*\()[^)]+(\)=(?R)|\)-(?R)|\)+(?R)|\)\*(?R)|\)\/(?R)|\)|)|[^,]+)

Answer (score 1):

The following regexp returns a match for each of the entries in your array.

```
/(?<=^|,)(?:([^\[\],]*)|(\[([^\[\]]*)\]))(?=$|,)/g
```

Comment: Your answer also solved my problems,too.